# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code for R.swift

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10.3, r.swift

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code for R.swift

[image]

[image]

Does any one have faced this situation?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer Found** from https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift#cocoapods-recommended

**"$PODS_ROOT/R.swift/rswift" generate "$SRCROOT/R.generated.swift"**

[image]

[image]

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;** Update to the latest version of [R.swift](https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift)

This is a security warning from macOS, because the `rswift` executable your using wasn’t [notarized](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09032019a). As of version 5.2.2 of R.swift, the executable is now fully notarized, so this problem shouldn’t happen anymore.

Note: when you install [R.swift](https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift) via CocoaPods, the quarantine bit isn’t set, so this warning doesn’t show up.